# is it better reading data from two unrelated tables or creating one table which summarizes them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to tables: Messages and Favorites and a Dashboard list to feed.
Messages table is structured like this:

```
from_user_id | to_user_id | message | timestamp
```

The Favorites table is structured like this:

```
user_id | fav_user_id | timestamp
```

The dashboard list has to be fed like this:
if dashboard owner (that is loggedin user) exchanged messages or has favorited another user, this user must be added to the dashboard list.
**My question is**: is it better to populate the dashboard by reading the two tables when dashboard needs to be loaded or creating another table called "dashboard" which summarizes the other two tables content and eventually reading dashboard list only from it?
Note: the dashboard table is populated like this: when a new row is added to tables Messages or Favorites a check is done on the Dashboard table to see if it has to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your `dashboard` is acting like a cache for the data in `messages` and `favorites`.

When you think about it this way, you are asking:

### Is it better to derive and cache statistics or read directly from 2 tables?

There is no correct answer.  But, understand that applying caching this way my be a case of premature optimization, which you can Google for.

Adding a layer of calculation between your source data and your display data simply adds one more place where things can:

- be stale
- be calculated incorrectly
- have stale definitions

If you want to change the row definition of `messages` or `favorites`, you might also need to change the definition of `dashboard` to hold the new information, you would also have to update the trigger/event/callback that updates `dashboard` when new data is inserted.  This may not sound like a big deal, but when someone says "The data on this page is wrong" you will start debugging by looking at the code that makes that page, not a hidden callback/listener triggered when data on another page is updated.

IMO, simplicity trumps cleverness everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it as two tables. Adding the two together means that you repeat data when you don't need to. Something like from_user_id | to_user_id | message | timestamp| is_fav | fav_timestamp would be needed and the last two columns would just be the same data for every message, unless you are looking to track changes in that status over time.